# Вопрос по архитектуре приложения

Tags: c#, .net

Пишу приложение, которое управляет некоторым устройством по com-порту.
Информационный обмен осуществляется по принципу запрос-ответ, но устройство
так же может само отправлять сообщения без команды от приложения (при обнаружении неисправности или изменении состояния).

Необходимо реализовать возможность удаленного управления этим устройством и написать программу-клиента. У первого приложения появляется два режима работы - "ручной", в котором управление устройством осуществляется через интерфейс программы, и "удаленный" - управление по сети с клиентской прогрммы на другой машине. Структурно это выглядит так:

Client  <---tcp--->  Server  <---com---> Device

Варианты решения:

Первый вариант - продублировать все команды из прокотола взаимодействия компа
и устройства (Server-Device) в протоколе взаимодействия двух компов (Client-Server). Очевидный минус - слишком много рутины, если протокол большой - нужно продублировать каждую команду, в каждой проверить корректность входных аргументов, отдельно все это оттестировать...

Второй вариант - в протоколе TCP сделать одну команду - "Отправить массив байт в устройство", таким образом Server выступает в роли шлюза - данные никак не анализирует, а всё, что ему пришло в этой команде просто перенаправляет в com-порт, если режим работы "удаленный". А получив ответ от устройства этот массив байт передает по сети клиенту.

Третий вариант - что-то вроде web-сервиса, NetRemoting и тд. Что бы клиентское ПО создало прокси-объект и всё взаимодействие осуществляло через него. 
С этими технологиями не работал ни разу, поэтому если этот вариант жизнеспособный, подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком направлении двигаться.

Есть ли более удачные решения?

Comment: Есть ещё вариант с хардварным адаптером вроде https://lavaports.com/ether-serial-links/ - когда-то делали с ним проект, более-менее стабильно работало.

Comment: Сделать на сервере API через веб интерфейс и делать любой клиент для подключения к нему: хоть локально, хоть удаленно через смартфон, хоть в другую программу встраивать.